# HABTM - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to create a simple bookmarking functionality in my Rails app.

Here are my models:

```
# post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collections
end

# collection.rb
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end

# collections_posts.rb
class CollectionsPosts < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Now I'm trying to write a really simple thing - adding a relation between `post` and `collection`:

```
post = Post.find(1)
collection = Collection.find(1)
collection.posts << collection
```

This code gives me following error:

```
undefined method `posts' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000100c81da0>
```

I have no idea why there is no `posts` method, because I have plenty of other relations defined in exact same way and they work well, although they are not HABTM.

Can you please advise me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: First I guess your `CollectionsPosts` is not useful here, it's mandatory to have the 'join model' when using the `has_many through` association. Do you have the required table in your database i.e. `collections_posts` ?

Comment: i added it just to check if it will change anything but it doesn't. Anyway - i'm getting this error no matter if there is a `CollectionsPosts` model or not ;) yes, i do have this table

Comment: It's strange that you get the error for an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which I presume means that `collection` is a relation. The result of a `find` though should be the actual record, not a relation. Are you sure you're not doing anything else not shown here?

Comment: here is the whole method (`User.collect_post()`. It's in `User` model and `Collection` belongs_to `User`) but i can't find anything wrong in it: https://gist.github.com/4492062

Comment: Well there's your problem. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @pjam no worries! your answer is more detailed than what I was going to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could really make your collect_post method way simpler, something like that should work :

```
def collect_post(post, collection_title = 'Favourites')

  # Find a collection by its name
  collection = Collection.find_by_name(title: collection_title) # this will return a collection object and not an ActiveRecord::Relation

  # if there is no such collection, create one!
  if collection.blank?
    collection = Collection.create user: self, title: collection_title
  end

  collection.posts << post

end
```

Note that there might be a better way to do that, but it's shorter that what you did originally and should fix your original error